# Method does not exist or incorrect signature invocable

Tags: apex, unit-test, invocable-method

Asked and answered here many times but I'm not finding this scenario. Getting method does not exist error when trying to invoke this Apex Class in my test.

```
global with sharing class Invocable_ObjectEntityDefinition {

    global class Request{

    @InvocableVariable(required=true)
    public String objectkey;

    }

    global class Response{

    @InvocableVariable(required=false)
    public String entityObjectName;

    @InvocableVariable(required=false)
    public Id objectMdtId;}

    @InvocableMethod(label='GetObjectName')
        global static List<Response> GetObjectName(List<Request> requests)

    {List<Response> erList = new List<Response>();
        Response er = new Response();

    // Should return just a single object
    hdone__Object__mdt o = [SELECT id, hdone__Object_Sfdc__r.QualifiedApiName
    FROM hdone__Object__mdt Where hdone__Object_Sfdc__r.KeyPrefix =: requests[0].objectkey Limit 1];

    er.entityObjectName = o.hdone__Object_Sfdc__r.QualifiedApiName;
    er.objectMdtId = o.Id;

    erList.add(er);

    return erList;}
}
```

Last line of test class is the issue:

```
private class Invocable_ObjectEntityDefinition_Test {

    @isTest
    static void GetObjectName(){

    List<String> objid = new list <String>();
            try{
                objid.add('001');
        }catch (System.DmlException e){
                System.debug('DML Exception: ' +
                             e.getDmlMessage(0));
            } catch (System.ListException e){
                System.debug('List Exception: ' +
                            e.getMessage());
        Invocable_ObjectEntityDefinition.GetObjectName(objid);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method takes a `List<Request>`, not a `List<String>`.

```
MyClass.Request request = new MyClass.Request();
request.objectKey = SObjectType.Account.getKeyPrefix();
List<MyClass.Request> requests = new List<MyClass.Request> { request };
MyClass.myMethod(requests);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your call does not match the signature of your `InvocableMethod`. This'll be easier to see if you annotate with the type of the variable and put the call side-by-side with the definition.

In your test class:

```
        (void) Invocable_ObjectEntityDefinition.GetObjectName(List<String> objid);
```

but in your definition:

```
    global static List<Response> GetObjectName(List<Request> requests)
```

Your `InvocableMethod` accepts a `List<Request>`, rather than a `List<String>`.

Your test class is also throwing away the `List<Response>` that the method returns. You'll probably want to capture that in a variable so that you can write assertions against it to validate the behavior.

You can also safely remove those `try`/`catch` blocks in your unit test. Those exceptions will not be thrown there.